# Edge effects on almost completely transparent objects

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I've got a semi-transparent outer block, and two semi-transparent inner blocks. I'm trying to animate the inner blocks fading out by bringing the transparency alpha to zero. I'm using Blender Internal.

My model looks like this:

[image]

These are wax blocks, with objects embedded inside. First, the small inner blocks are created separately as 2x1 blocks. Then they're placed next to each other to make a large 2x2 block. Once the outer wax is in place (a boolean modifier/plane reveals the outer wax) the inner wax should fade away, "melting" as it's replaced by the the outer wax.

The problem I'm having is that the sharp edges of the inner wax don't fade away as alpha approaches zero. My *guess* about what's going on is the amount of light that's reflected off the inner faces is unaffected by their material's transparency.

Effectively, I don't like the discontinuity between when alpha is very small, and when alpha is zero. Here's is the difference between the inner blocks transparency alpha at 0.001, and 0.000:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would it work to delete the inner face? (or give it some thickness?)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by giving it thickness, but I could give it a try. The inner blocks are outside and off by themselves earlier in the animation though, so I don't think deleting the face is an option.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. could you upload your .blend or make a mockup of how you want it to look? (nvm about giving it thickness, I thought that the inner block was one object with an internal face) Also, just to be clear, is the "nasty edge" an intersection of the two inner block objects?

Comment: See if my edits make more sense.. if not, I'll do up a .blend file.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. I fiddled around a bit, but I can't figure out how to make it go away. (I don't use BI much anymore)

Comment: Oh nooo!! Thanks for trying though :) I've been getting the feeling I'm shooting myself in the foot by investing time learning BI..

Comment: I tested this in Cycles, and while the edge is still there, it fades out gradually with the rest of the block.

Comment: Is the outer block raytraced or Z Transparency?

Comment: Hey, I think you solved it! It looks way better when I change the outer wax to z-transparency!

Comment: Is it time for the author of the question to post an "answer" which outlines the pros and cons of the various fixes he tried (with credit to the originators) and which he settled on as the "solution" to his specific problem ?

Comment: @ajwood I'm still not sure what you want, but if you solved it, it would be nice if you could add an answer to help others with the same problem.. :)

Comment: @gandalf3: woah, this is so old I'll have to figure out myself what I wanted :P I'll take a look this weekend and put something up.

Comment: @ajwood This is close to being closed, can you post an answer?

Comment: Oh jeeze, I forgot about this again! I'll post an answer tonight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem goes away if I switched the transparency of the outer block from raytraced to z-transparency.

[image]